# Use sed with variable, double quote, path

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I'm trying to modify a variable in a script with `sed`.
The variable is a reference to a path that I want to modify.

Is it possible to use `sed` in a file which modifies this script for the next time it's launched?

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
main () {
newdir="/okl/dfsdf/dfsf/"
sed -i "s|mnt="/*/"|mnt="\$newdir"|g" file
}

main
```

I expected the `mnt` variable to change but only the first time it is defined in the code, that's why I need to double quote `mnt="/*/"`.

Comment: You need to escape double quotes to make them literal _inside_ double quotes. To show what I mean: `"foo"'bar'"baz"` has a double-quoted string `foo`, a single-quoted string `bar`, and a double-quoted string `baz` concatenated together into a single string; it contains _no_ quote characters as literal contents.

Comment: a lot of things to comment on here, but *"change but only the first time"* is worthy. Add `set -vx at the top of 'main` and `set +vx` at the bottom. Save script and run. Run a second time. The lines with `+` are the lines of code that are actually executed. When you understand what you see is produced by what you have written, you will have learned a lot (-;. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advices ! Didn't know about set -vx

Comment: You have different answers of people who don't completely understand your problem. Perhaps you are smarter than we are, Please add example input file and show how it must look like after the `sed` command.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. You are welcome to clarify your original question, but changing the question when you have already received multiple answers is not acceptable. **Again,** accept one of the answers and post a new question with your *actual* requirements if you still need help. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to change a line like

```
mnt=/some/path/file
```

with

```
mnt=/okl/dfsdf/dfsf/file
```

You can use

```
newdir="/okl/dfsdf/dfsf/"
sed -i 's|mnt=.*/|mnt='$newdir'|' file
```

Comment: The problem is that the command is done in 'file', so it changes the sed argument because it's wrote mnt=

Comment: When the `sed` command is inside the file that you are trying to change, you have created a strange situation. You might be able to solve it by telling `sed` it should not (that is `!`) substitue anything that starts with `sed` (that is `/^sed/`). Command is  `sed -i  '/^sed /!s|mnt=.*/|mnt='$newdir'|' file`.

Comment: It will probably works I'll try that thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The immediate two problems are that you cannot nest double quotes, and `/"*"/` is almost certainly not the correct regex.

In regular expressions, `*` simply means to repeat the previous expression zero or more times, as many as possible. So you are matching `""`, `"""`, `""""` etc.

Guessing a bit as to what you might hope your code should do, I imagine you are looking for something like

```
sed -i "s|mnt=\"[^\"]*\"|mnt=\"$newdir\"|" file
```

The `g` flag says to match all occurrences on a line, but I imagine you don't expect to have more than one anyway.

Wrapping this into a function which you then immediately call only once is simply unnecessary code.

Comment: `sed -i 's|mnt="[^"]*"|mnt="'"$newdir"'"|' file` would arguably be clearer and less error-prone if enhanced in future since it'd only expose to shell the minimal part that has to exposed to shell (i.e. expanding the variable) while still protecting the rest of the script.

Comment: Can I do it with an exception on lines which contain "sed"

Comment: If you mean to not perform the substitution on those lines, `sed -i '/sed/!s...'`; but please don't heap on new requirements in comments. Ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements (but probably search first, and mention your own efforts in the question and explain why the related solutions you found don't qualify as duplicates - this is a fairly common FAQ).

Comment: Sorry didn't get so much times to try those code, and edit my post

Comment: I'll do it When I come back home

Answer (score 1):

IMO `c` command of `sed` suits better than `s`, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

scr=$(basename "$0")
new='"/tmp/dir2"'
mnt="/tmp/dir1"

echo "$scr $mnt"
sed -i '/mnt=/cmnt='"$new" "$scr"
```